# return the element of array java

Tags: java, python

Here's my Python code

```
def string(data):
    n=0
    while True:
        yield data[n]
        n+=1
        n%=len(data)
```

Here's my Java code calling the `string` method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lengthText; i++) {
              out[i] += string(t1) ^ string(t2);

         }
```

And the `string` method:

```
public byte string(byte[] a){
    int i = -1;
     while(true){
        i++;
        i%= a.length;
        return a[i];            
     }
}
```

If I understand correctly it should return the next item in the sequence data, as soon as the sequence ends - takes you to the beginning and so on to infinity.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. There's a lot of code here with no context or description

Comment: Where does _lengthText_ come from?

Comment: `yield data[n]` in pyton is not the same as `return a[i];` in java

Comment: lengthText is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct substitute for `yield` in Java. You could try to simulate it with some small class e.g.

```
class YieldSubstitute<Data> {
    private int    n;
    private Data[] data;

    public YieldSubstitute(Data[] data) {
        this.n    = 0;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data getNext() {
        Data toReturn = data[n];
        n = (n + 1) % data.length;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

and then using it like:

```
YieldSubstitute<Data> ys = new YieldSubstitute<Data>(data);
Data data1 = ys.getNext();
Data data2 = ys.getNext();
...
```

During situations like that you need to remember that `yield` is Python specific element and to use it in Java first you need to find some common denominator - you can achieve that carefully analyzing what your function is actually doing.

On a side note - your usage of generators is invalid. You should initialize it first with arguments and then obtain sequence of results:

```
generator = string(data)
data1 = next(generator)
data2 = next(generator)
...
```

Your Java code is basically a for of infinite loops that are broken on their first iteration. You should learn more about difference between `return` an `yield` in python before you try to treat `yield` as if it was `return`.

**EDIT**: From your description what you need is:

```
byte[] out = new byte[lengthText]; // initialized with 0s
int n = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthText; i++) {
    out[i] = data1[n] ^ data2[n]; // assuming that both arrays have more that 0 elements
    n = (n + 1) % Math.min(data1.length, data2.length); // just in case their length differ
}
```

where `data1` and `data2` are both of type `byte[]`. If their lengths are guaranteed to be equal you can skip the `Math.min` thing.

Comment: All I need is to obtain every element of array and apply the XOR operation to them . And make the new array after this operation. But the new array should be the specific size (lengthText), I mean if the array to which we apply XOR is end it should return to the first element and continued the operation while the the new array would be the size of "lengthText". I am sorry that I can not explain clearry but I am beginner.

Comment: Take a look at my edit and say if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: not exactly( But my code start to work correctly :)))) Maybe it not good but now it working. I try to make it better. Thank you for your time and help.